# Is the derivative of $|x|$ defined for every x in the neighborhood?

Tags: continuity

> Is the derivative of $f(x)= |x|$ defined for every $x$ in the neighborhood?

I know the derivative of $x=0^+$ and $x=0^-$ is not the same. But is it correct to say that the derivative is defined for every $x$ in the neighborhood of $0$?

Comment: It is defined for all points except 0

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not correct, since $0$ belongs to every neighborhood of $0$, and $f$ is not differentiable at $0$.